# Computing eigenvectors and eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a (non-sparse) $9 \times 9$ matrix and I wish to obtain its eigenvalues and eigenvectors. Of course, the eigenvalues can be quite a pain as we will probably not be able to find the zeros of its characteristic polynomial.

Actually, what I really want is find the eigenvector belonging to the largest eigenvalue. Would the following code give me this: `Eigenvectors[matrix, 1]`?

How does Mathematica do this? Is there some kind of algorithm of which's existence I am unaware that computes the eigenvector belonging to the largest eigenvalue?

Can the largest eigenvalue be computed numerically (in modulus or even throw away all the complex ones), and then the eigenvectors pseudo-analytically using `Eigenvectors`?

Added: The matrix is symbolical.

Comment: I am in the old post here. Have anyone found the way to generate the eigenvectors and eigenvalues as ordered? I mean I get the eigenvector matrix but the eigenvalues are not for the corresponding eigenvectors. New to mathematica any help appreciated

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The function to obtain both the eigenvalues and the eigenvectors is `Eigensystem`. Use it as `{eigVals,eigVecs} = Eigensystem[matrix]`.

If the matrix is symbolic, then the output (if you wait long enough for it to churn out an answer!) will only be as a list of general solutions for the roots of a 9th order polynomial with unknown coefficients, and there are no closed form solutions for polynomials with orders greater than 4. The results will not have any particular ordering.

On the other hand, a `9x9` numerical matrix is a piece of cake (even if you were to solve the characteristic polynomial), so you should have no problems.

To obtain the largest (first) eigenvalue and the corresponding eigenvector, use the optional second argument as `Eigensystem[matrix, 1]`. Here's an example (with a smaller matrix to keep the output small):

```
mat = RandomInteger[{0, 10}, {3, 3}];
{eigVals, eigVecs} = Eigensystem[mat] // N

(* Out[1]= {{21.4725, 6.39644, 0.131054}, {{1.3448, 0.904702, 1.}, 
            {0.547971, -1.99577, 1.}, {-0.935874, -0.127319, 1.}}} *)

{eigVal1, eigVec1} = Eigensystem[mat, 1] // N
(* Out[2]= {{21.4725}, {{1.3448, 0.904702, 1.}}} *)
```

Comment: Well, the matrix is not numerical but largely symbolical. Mathematica is unable to obtain the eigenvalues except if I set a few terms to $0$. If I ask Mathematica to output the characteristic polynomial it claims it consists out of more than 50k terms!

Comment: Thanks! My matrix is symbolical but I do have numerical values for the parameters and hence I have a numerical matrix. How does Mathematica find eigenvalues for a $9 \times 9$ matrix? How can it solve the characteristic polynomial? Anyway, I wanted to have symbolic expressions for the eigenvalues as I wanted to let one parameter vary and plot the result. Would the best way now be (using Mathematica) that for a few data points I compute the eigenvalues and make a plot of that?

Comment: @JonasTeuwen What is the structure of your matrix? Which of the 81 elements is your free parameter (and the rest numerical)? I'm afraid, I don't know how Mathematica calculates the eigenvalues symbolically.

Comment: @JonasTeuwen Is the only reason you want a symbolic solution that you want to plot it?  If so, use `With[{mat = matrix}, f[x_?NumericQ] := Eigenvalues[mat, 1]]`, then `Plot[f[x], {x, xmin, xmax}]` (assuming that `x` is the parameter according to which you want to plot).  Don't compute it for selected data points manually, just let `Plot` work it's [adaptive sampling magic](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/AdaptivePlotting/).  Also note that which root is the largest might easily depend on the parameter, so the plot could have a discontinuous derivative.

Comment: @JonasTeuwen That `With` from my previous comment won't work for injecting the value (localization kicks in), but just copy the matrix expression manually into `Eigenvalues` when you define the function.

Comment: Thanks both of you! I'm still a bit puzzled by how Mathematica would be able to compute (symbolically) the eigenvalues of a $9 \times 9$ matrix. Sure, certain characteristic polynomials can have easy zeros, but in general?

Comment: @JonasTeuwen Who is claiming that it is able to find symbolic eigenvalues for a 9 by 9 matrix? (not in terms of `RootOf`)

Comment: @acl: Well, this post says: "A 9x9 matrix is a piece of cake (even if you were to solve the characteristic polynomial), so you should have no problems."

Comment: I ithink he means that it's a piece of cake for numerical matrices. In any case 9th order polynomials cannot be solved analytically in general (and with reasonable definitions of analytical)

Comment: @JonasTeuwen Mathematica has a general way to represent roots of polynomials, even for the cases when they can't be written explicitly in terms of roots.  The solution was be full of `Root` objects, the meaning of which is just "the $n^\mathrm{th}$ root of this polynomial within".

Comment: @JonasTeuwen What Szabolcs says is why `Solve[x^76 + x^65 + x^97 + x^23 + x^42 - 1 == 0, x]` does return a set of solutions, which are what I excluded by referring to "reasonable definitions of analytical" in my previous comment.

Comment: @JonasTeuwen Looks like you completely missed my last paragraph. I've edited to bring it further up in the answer.

Comment: Okay, right. I see. By the way. We do can find "closed form solutions" for general polynomials of say the fifth degree in terms of special functions (but not by repeated root taking, that's what follows from Galois Theory).

Comment: @Jonas yes, anything can be solved by defining a special function that is defined by the property of solving it.

Comment: It can actually be done using theta functions. See "Resolution of algebraic equations by theta constants" by Hiroshi Umemura.

Comment: @Jonas thanks, I was not aware of that. I have seen articles obtaining the roots of specific polynomials in terms of hypergeometric functions (this was in the context of writing down wavefunctions for what is called the Calogero-Sutherland model in mathematical physics). I am afraid it's al over my head though. By the way, if you wish to notify someone of your comment, add a @ like I did here.

Comment: The eigenvalues are not sorted from the largest to the smallest in some cases.

Answer (score 7):

If the matrix is completely numerical (not symbolic), then `Eigenvalues` will return eigenvalues by descending magnitude.  Therefore `Eigenvalues[matrix, 1]` will always give the largest eigenvalue and `Eigenvector[matrix, 1]` will give the corresponding eigenvector.  As R.M. said, both can be obtained at the same time using `Eigensystem`.

There are different numerical methods for obtaining the eigenvector that corresponds to the largest eigenvalue (by magnitude), the most common being [power iteration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_iteration).

If the matrix is symbolic, the eigenvalues/vectors are not ordered (as far as I know).

Comment: If the matrix is symbolic, the eigenvectors are unordered, correct.

Answer (score 4):

Re the question as to how *Mathematica* finds eigenvalues: in the Documentation Center look up "implementation"; you'll find a link to the page `tutorial/SomeNotesOnInternalImplementation`. And there, in the section Exact Numerical Linear Algebra you'll find the explanation, "`Eigenvalues` works by interpolating the characteristic polynomial."

Answer (score 3):

[`Eigensystem`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Eigensystem.html) will give you the eigenvalues and eigenvectors, the rest is a matter of sorting and extracting that data.

```
(* Calculates the eigenvector with the largest eigenvalue *)
largestEV[m_] := Sort[
    Transpose@Eigensystem[m],
    #1[[1]] < #2[[1]] &
][[1, 2]]

m = {{1, 1, 0}, {0, 2, 0}, {0, 2, 3}}
largestEV[m]
```

> ```
>  {1, 0, 0}
> ```

Comment: Why complicate when you can use the second argument for `Eigensystem`? See my answer...

Comment: This generalizes easier, suppose you wanted the eigenvector closest to the average eigenvalue etc. Also, I'm not sure how the standard ordering works for complex eigenvalues.

Comment: For complex eigenvalues, the ordering is decreasing `Abs[eigenvalues]`

Comment: Why would it generalize easier? Eigensystem[mat, All]

Comment: @ruebenko That's what I did.