# Local variables

Tags: scoping

I'm trying to use `Modules` together with functions.

```
tmp2 = x^2 + 1; f[y_] := Module[{x = 1}, Evaluate[y tmp2]]
```

This works when I just have

```
tmp2 = x^2 + 1; Module[{x = 1}, Evaluate[tmp2]]
```

But `f[1]` outputs $1 + x^2$.

**Edit:** After seeing the answers I wonder how I can get something like this to work:

```
ClearAll[withRules]
SetAttributes[withRules, HoldAll]
withRules[rules_, expr_] := 
 Internal`InheritedBlock[{Rule, RuleDelayed}, 
  SetAttributes[{Rule, RuleDelayed}, HoldFirst];
  Unevaluated[expr] /. rules]
ClearAll[f, tmp2]
tmp2[y_] = y (x^2 + 1)
withRules[{expr -> tmp2}, f[y_] := Module[{x = 1}, expr[y]]]
```

**Edit 2:** Maybe it is better if I explain what I'd like to do.

I have a lot of calculations in terms of $k_x$, $k_y$ and $k_z$. So, those are outputted in terms of these three variables. However, sometimes I need to integrate such expressions but to do this I need to use spherical coordinates. So I set $k_x = k \sin(a) \cos(b)$ and so on and then integrate. I don't want the transformations always set because I want the other calculations to have $k_x$, $k_y$ and $k_z$ as variables, not $a$ en $b$.

Comment: Please post a minimal example. We don't know what Trew does (nor does it seem to be relevant to the question), we don't know what result you're expecting or not expecting, the code is not indented properly and therefore hard to read.

Comment: @David: Good points. I think I have reduced the problem to what my problem is...

Comment: It works fine for me: http://imgur.com/3SatR - maybe you didn't clear some variables and have unwanted side effects? Can you reproduce the error with your example?

Comment: @David: After restarting the kernel I get this: http://i.imgur.com/fFNw8.png. And why does it output $5$ for you? $1^2 + 1 = 2$ I'd say...

Comment: Please see my edit for one possibility

Answer (score 6):

Ok, let me tell you straight away that what you are trying to do is likely to be a bad idea. Now, let me explain. The problem you face on the surface is that `Evaluate` is only effective at the first level inside heads which hold their arguments. Since you have `SetDelayed[f[y_],Module[...]]`, the stuff inside `Module` is too deep. You need `With` to inject arbitrarily deep, so we try:

```
ClearAll[f, x];
With[{tmp = tmp2},
   f[y_] := Module[{x = 1}, y tmp]]
```

However, now you face another problem: variable renaming mechanism in scoping constructs tries to protect the scoping and renames variables in part of your code:

```
?f
Global`f
f[y$_]:=Module[{x$=1},y$ (1+x^2)]
```

Here is what you can do to achieve your goal:

```
ClearAll[f, x];
Block[{tmp}, Unevaluated[f[y_] := Module[{x = 1}, y*tmp]] /. tmp -> tmp2]
```

This is explained in details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6236458/plot-using-with-versus-plot-using-block-mathematica/6236808#6236808). Note however that the fact that we had to go against the system *twice* tells us already that this is a fragile and generally bad practice. Please see more discussion on that in the linked answer.

**EDIT**

In response to the edit in the question: in your case, I suggest to use `Block` and create a dynamic environment, where to execute the code for which you *do* want your transformations:

```
SetAttributes[withTransforms,HoldAll];
withTransforms[code_]:=
 Block[{kx=k*Sin[a]*Cos[b],ky=k*Sin[a]*Sin[b],kz=k*Cos[b]},
   code
 ]
```

This will allow you to selectively enable these definitions:

```
withTransforms[Integrate[kx^2+ky^2,{a,0,2 Pi}]]
```

Comment: I feel this is my fault, please see where this question may have come from: [this comment](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2012/computing-eigenvectors-and-eigenvalues#comment5430_2014) and the preceding one.  I was trying to squeeze into the comment a way to define that `f` function (to compute the eigenvalue) in terms of the already existing matrix.  Since you are saying that this is bad practice, I felt it necessary to link to that discussion.  I agree that this is a messy thing and should be avoided when possible, but occasionally it's useful.

Comment: @Szabolcs You don't sound logical now. Either you agree with my point that this is not a good practice, but then your answer (which, in fact, is not very different from mine except this point) does not reflect that, or you don't, but then why saying the question is your fault?

Comment: @Szabolcs As to the occasional usefullness, I agree generally but strongly disagree for this particular class of use cases, because I think that taking the scope apart in this way is very fragile. I do sometimes use definition-time replacements, like e.g. in the `lex` function from [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1602/resource-management-in-mathematica/1603#1603), but I try to avoid breaking scope, particularly nested scope, and particularly with global objects. This was also endlessly discussed on Mathgroup and lead to lots of trouble in all cases I remember.

Answer (score 3):

What you are trying to do is generate code (a function definition) programmatically.

There are several techniques to programmatically generate code.  The main tool we need is injecting held expressions into other held expression.  The usual way to do it is using `With`:

```
tmp2 = x^2 + 1;

With[{expr = tmp2},
 f[y_] := Module[{x = 1}, y expr]
]
```

Now let's check the function definition:

```
?f

Global`f
f[y$_]:=Module[{x$=1},y$ (1+x^2)]
```

You can see that Mathematica's localization mechanism has renamed `x` to `x$` in `Module`, so this didn't work.

In these situations we can usually use some solution based on `Replace` or `ReplaceAll`.

It's advantageous to have this packaged up into a function.  I tend to use the `withRules` function that I described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8617773/695132):

```
ClearAll[withRules]
SetAttributes[withRules, HoldAll]
withRules[rules_, expr_] :=
  First@PreemptProtect@Internal`InheritedBlock[
    {Rule, RuleDelayed},
    SetAttributes[{Rule, RuleDelayed}, HoldFirst];
    Hold[expr] /. rules
]
```

It is used in a similar way to `With`, but is does not localize variables like `With` does.

```
Clear[f]
withRules[{expr -> tmp2},
 f[y_] := Module[{x = 1}, y expr]
]
```

Checking the definition of `f` again we can see that now it is what we intended:

```
?f

Global`f
f[y_]:=Module[{x=1},y (1+x^2)]
```

I have asked a related question recently, and in that post you'll find a slightly more general expression injection function (`inject[]`), as well as several other expression injection techniques described in the answers:

- [Injecting a sequence of expressions into a held expression](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1929/injecting-a-sequence-of-expressions-into-a-held-expression)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I don't think I should delete this time.  I agree with @Leonid that often it is not good practice to do this (especially since `tmp2` is global), but there are legitimate situations, and I was in fact trying to do this an hour ago [in this comment](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2012/computing-eigenvectors-and-eigenvalues#comment5430_2014)

Comment: @JonasTeuwen Why won't you just use `Integrate[expr /. kx -> k Sin[a] Cos[b], {a, ...}, {b, ...}]` then?  You should almost never need to use code generation for this kind of thing.  As we say, it's like shooting at a sparrow with a cannon (and it's a cannon that can fire back this time---I have to agree with Leonid on that)

Comment: Thanks. (I had deleted my comment as I thought it would be better to just put this in my original post). I came to this "idea" while searching for "local variables mathematica".