# Using With in combination with Graphics

Tags: graphics, assignment

Assume that we are given a symbol `p={x,y}` which should represent a 2D point. If `x` and `y` have numerical values then we can plot the point uisng

```
Graphics[Point[p]]
```

Next, I wanted to plot some setting for various `x` and `y`, so I thought I could use the `With` command and have something like:

```
With[{x = 1, y = 1},
 Graphics[Point[p]]
 ]
```

This doesn't work. I guess it has something to do with the order of evaluations, holding stuff etc. but I cannot figure out how to solve this.

So the question is how to use `With` together with `Graphics`?

Comment: @gpap: This is clear, but I want to use `p` as in my real example the definition of `p` depends on `x` and `y` in a somewhat more complicated manner.

Comment: @gpap: I have a point which depends on several variables. So you say that the only way is to define `p` as a *function* of the various symbols that define it?

Comment: Maybe the problem is the (understanding or wording) of the documentation of [With](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/With.html) ? So what is not clear about With? @gpap: just post your comment as an answer.

Comment: @RolfMertig: I guess I don't understand the documentation. When I read *"specifies that in `expr` occurrences of the symbols `x`, `y`, should be replaced by `Subscript[x, 0]`, `Subscript[y, 0]`* I expect that as `x` and `y` occur in `p` they should (recursively) replaced.

Comment: No, that's not right - no recursion is taking place. I had a look around and your question can be answered by [the answer I linked to](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/559/what-are-the-use-cases-for-different-scoping-constructs/569#569) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6236458/plot-using-with-versus-plot-using-block-mathematica/6236808#6236808)

Comment: I think this question should be closed as a duplicate of the threads that @gpap linked.  If you agree please vote to close.

Comment: This works : `Block[{x = 1, y = 1}, Graphics[Point[p]]]`

Comment: I decided to post an answer to this question as I think there is a nontrivial interpretation, even if the OP didn't intend it.  Perhaps it should still be closed but I thought this might be of interest.

Comment: @Dror But With has Attribute HoldAll. Please read about Hold, evaluation etc.

Comment: Similar [question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2026/local-variables) about `Module`.

Comment: a simple answer would be `With[{x = 1, y = 1}, Evaluate@Graphics[Point[p]]]`. It does have to do with order of evaluation.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard  Is the duplicate on SO a sufficient reason for closing on SE?  I don't know how integrated or independent the sites are meant to be.  To my mind, the answer on SE linked by gpap explains how to use scoping constructs but does not warn how not to use them for this case.  I think the distinction is important for someone still getting familiar with *Mathematica*'s order of evaluation and localization.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yes, especially [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/559/what-are-the-use-cases-for-different-scoping-constructs/633#633) and, less directly, [this one](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/559/what-are-the-use-cases-for-different-scoping-constructs/565#565)

Comment: @acl That is already in my answer (which is now CW, by the way).

Comment: @Mr.Wizard indeed; I had missed it

Answer (score 3):

The trivial answer is: don't use `With`, use `Block`:

```
p := {x, y}

Block[{x = 1, y = 1},
 Graphics[Point[p]]
]
```

The question remains how one can use `With`.  It is possible with `Evaluate`:

```
With[{x = 1, y = 1},
 Graphics[Point[p]] // Evaluate
]
```

This contravenes the expected behavior of `With` which normally replaces symbols *before* evaluation.  It works in this case because nothing (bad) happens when you evaluate the incomplete `Graphics` expression; errors only appear on display.  In other cases you may need to prevent evaluation of the full expression, yet you wish to make a substitution.  This amounts to in-place evaluation, so you will need something like the [Trott-Strzebonski method for In-Place Evaluation](http://library.wolfram.com/conferences/devconf99/villegas/UnevaluatedExpressions/Links/index_lnk_30.html), or this method that [WReach introduced](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2683/121) me to:

```
Unevaluated[Print[Hold[p]]] /. HoldPattern[p] :> RuleCondition @ Block[{x = 1, y = 1}, p]
```

> Hold[{1,1}]

Or, since `p` is a Symbol and not an arbitrary pattern we may use the ["injector pattern"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1937/121):

```
Block[{x = 1, y = 1}, p] /. p_ :> Print[Hold[p]]
```

> Hold[{1,1}]

I replaced `Graphics` with `Print`, and `Point` with `Hold` so that the holding and evaluation behavior would be apparent.