# Plot the lowest eigenvalues of a parametric matrix

Tags: plotting, matrix

The question here is somewhat related to the comments in 
[Computing eigenvectors and eigenvalues](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2012/computing-eigenvectors-and-eigenvalues)

I have a matrix M, say 400 by 400, and all elements depend explicitly on one parameter t in a quadratic form. That's to say, for one given t, I can calculate each element and write down the full matrix explicitly.

I would like to try different t, say a list of t(s), see how the lowest eigenvalues change with respect to t and plot it. I tried something like `assuming` and `with` but it did not work well. Anyone has an idea how to do it efficiently? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ClearAll[mat, minev]
SeedRandom[1]
rm = RandomInteger[10, {400, 400, 3}];

mat[t_] := rm.{1, t, t^2};
minev[t_?NumericQ] := Eigenvalues[mat[t], -1];

DiscretePlot[Evaluate[minev[t]], {t, 0, 1, .01}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks. You always come to my rescue....

Comment: @James, i am glad i could help. Thank you for the Accept.

Comment: by the way, do you think it possible to get the exact coordinates of the points after I plot? Also, is it possible change the scale of y axis after I plot? I know we have lots of options in the plotting function and we can set them before running the plot command.

Comment: @James, to extract the point coords from `dp = DicretePlot[...];` you can use `Cases[dp, Point[x_] :> x, {0, Infinity}][[1]]`. For the second question, you can use `Show[dp, PlotRange->{a,b}]` to change the `y` axis range to `{a,b}`.