# Optimize a parametric matrix to get a lowest possible eigenvalue

Tags: plotting, matrix, mathematical-optimization, linear-algebra

This question is a followup of [Plot the lowest eigenvalues of a parametric matrix](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/114282/plot-the-lowest-eigenvalues-of-a-parametric-matrix)

Now I can get the lowest eigenvalue LowEign(t) of the matrix for a given t numerically.

When I plot the LowEign with respect to t, I find it a perfect convex function in the region of interesting t, which means I can find a t* to give the lowest LowEign (the lowest of the lowest eigenvalue of the matrix). See here:
[image: LowEign with respect to t]

Now I hope to get the t* at a much higher precision, say 6 decimal places. Instead of plotting in a much smaller interval, I try using `NMinimize`or `Minimize` function like:

```
NMinimize[{Eigenvalues[M[t_], -1], t > 2.3 && t < 2.4}, t]
```

or

```
NMinimize[{Min[Eigenvalues[M[t_]]], t > 2.3 && t < 2.4}, t]
```

but the output is the same:

```
Eigenvalues::eival: Unable to find all roots of the characteristic polynomial.
```

I suspect that MMA is trying to solve the `Eigenvalues[M[t_], -1]` or `Min[Eigenvalues[M[t_]]]` analytically but failed.

Note: I converted the Matrix M into a numerical instead of symbolic representation of t before using the Minimization.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### First answer (extended comment actually)

You have to define better your objective function. For example, the following works:

```
ClearAll[mat, minev]
SeedRandom[1]
rm = RandomInteger[10, {40, 40, 3}];

mat[t_] := N[rm.{1, t, t^2}];
minev[t_?NumericQ] := First@Eigenvalues[mat[t], -1];

Take[Table[minev[t], {t, 0, 1, .01}], 3]

(* {-0.864071 - 1.30548 I, -0.861327 - 1.21718 I, -0.859129 - 
  1.12321 I} *)

DiscretePlot[Abs@minev[t], {t, 0, 1, .01}]
```

[image]

```
ClearAll[mf]
mf[M_, t_?NumericQ] := First@Eigenvalues[M[t], -1];

NMinimize[{Abs[mf[mat, t]], 0.25 < t < 0.4}, t]

(* {7.13047*10^-11, {t -> 0.323957}} *)
```

### Optimizing for larger matrices

For larger matrices we can use memoization and a coarser grid of numbers:

```
ClearAll[rm, mat]
rm = RandomInteger[10, {400, 400, 3}];
mat[t_] := N[rm.{1, t, t^2}];

ClearAll[mf, mfChop]
mf[M_, t_?NumericQ] := mfChop[M, Round[t*10^6]/10^6.];
mfChop[M_, t_?NumericQ] := mfChop[M, t] = First@Eigenvalues[M[t], -1];

AbsoluteTiming[
 sol = NMinimize[{Abs[mf[mat, t]], 0.25 < t < 0.4}, t, PrecisionGoal -> 5]
]

(* {11.9561, {4.85666*10^-6, {t -> 0.330967}}} *)
```

This is the value found:

```
Round[(t /. sol[[2]])*10^6]/10^6.

(* 0.330967 *)
```

#### Visualizing the minimization with memoized points

We can visually verify that the mininmization process proceeded as expected plotting the memoized points together with the actual points.

```
memPoints = 
  Cases[DownValues[
    mfChop], (_[mfChop[mat, x_]] :> y_) :> {x, y}, \[Infinity]];

ListPlot[{#[[1]], Abs[#[[2]]]} & /@ memPoints, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotTheme -> "Detailed", PlotStyle -> Red]
```

[image]

Using non-memoizing function for the next plot:

```
Clear[minev]
minev[t_?NumericQ] := First@Eigenvalues[mat[t], -1];

Show[{
  DiscretePlot[Abs@minev[t], {t, 0, 1, .005}],
  ListPlot[{#[[1]], Abs[#[[2]]]} & /@ memPoints, 
   PlotTheme -> "Detailed", PlotStyle -> Red]}]
```

[image]

Comment: I guess my matrix 400 by 400 is too expensive to evaluate? I use your code but after 30mins it is still running....

Comment: @James My first answer was more of an extended comment... See my update with an implementation that gets the result for $400 \times 400$ matrix within 15 seconds on my laptop.